# percent describes per 100, what term is used to describe 'per one' as in probabilities [0, 1]?

Tags: probability, terminology

I'm building a units based type for C++ which describes probabilities (using boost::units library.) While I know that the values of probabilities are dimensionless, I think it makes some sense in the same way that angles (another dimensionless quantity) are often given units. My question is given that percent is a reasonable unit for parts per 100, is there some such concept for `parts per unit/one`? Following the etymology of `percent` (from per centum) I arrived at per unus (latin for one) => perun. However, I would prefer not making one up.

Comment: Please give an example sentence where you would want to use this term.

Comment: proportion? fraction? probability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Proportion** or **fraction** (if out of one) or **percentage** (if out of 100) seem pretty innocuous and easy to interpret. Other bases may work too, like parts-per-million, depending on your intended domain. For example, some fields report outcomes as X per 100,000 patients or parts per million.
- You could label them as **relative frequencies** (or something like `r_freq`), though this (obviously) has an  frequentist slant and might be a little bit odd if the probability is being used to describe something like a degree of belief.  On the other hand, if you're explicitly encoding subjective beliefs, you could call them **credences** (or maybe `cred` for short).
- There isn't anything weird about calling the units **probability**, in the same way we often label an angle as being "in radians" even though angles are, in fact, dimensionless.
- You could coin your own term, though I have a strong but viseral dislike of "perunus"--it just looks weird. It's emtymologically tempting, but I would strongly suggest not overloading [probit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit_model) either--it's confusing.
- In some situations, it might be more natural to use odds instead of probability, which you could label as **odds** or **odds ratio**. I suppose there's also the **[Hartley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartley_(unit))** or **ban/deciban** too, though these aren't quite probabilities (and have a very old-fashioned, Bletchley-park sort of feeling to them).

Finally, make sure that you're distinguishing between probabilities (which are dimensionless) and probability densities, which have units of $\frac{1}{\text{whatever}}$ (and, obviously, may be larger than one).

Answer (score 6):

I usually use the term "proportion".

Comment: Fraction also works

Answer (score 0):

A percent is just another way to represent any fraction by scaling it to be out of 100. You could do this for your scenario since something like .25/1 is obviously 25% of 1. It seems like there isn't a special term since there doesn't need to be.